# Error when compiling vue js front end in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to run this app

```
https://github.com/saeedvaziry/laravel-vue-polling-app.git
```

However when i run the command

```
npm run watch
```

as in README.md file i am getting the following error

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Package exports for 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\laravel-vue-polling-app\node_modules\@babel\helper-compilation-targets' do not define a '.' subpath
    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:485:15)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:577:20)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
    at require (C:\Users\user\Desktop\laravel-vue-polling-app\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
...........
```

What is casuing this error, is webpack config invalid, what am i missing here, please help to resolve

Comment: Shot in the dark, but this might be useful here: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10997

Comment: Make sure you are running the latest npm, remove lock and node_modules folder and try again. Try installing dependencies via `npm install --no-bin-links`

Answer (score 0):

Look at following [issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10997) on github try to delete the `node_modules` directory and reinstall it using

`npm install`